# Testing checksum by modifying a file

Tags: c#, testing, copy, sha512

A program in C# which copy a file or whole folders to another folder is made and in that application checksum SHA-512 has been used to verify that input and output of the copy process is/are identical, the program works fine but I need to test the whole program and especially test or verify the checksum. how can I, give the program an input e.g. a file and in the process modify the file somehow in order to see that checksum detect that error? thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Read a file, calculate checksum, modify a byte, write file, recalculate checksum.

Comment: You should write your checksum algorithm to work with streams. Then you could write a unit test that uses a `MemoryStream` bound to an array. You could then change one of the bytes in the array to verify that the checksum is different before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of testing the SHA512 hash. Here we have two tests, TestSHA512Modify and TestSHA512Append. One modifies bytes within the file, open appends bytes to the file. Both are useful tests of the Hash.

```
static void TestSHA512Modify()
{
    var testFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    CreateRandomFile(testFile, 1024);

    var sha12 = GetFileSHA512(testFile);
    Console.WriteLine("TestSHA12Modify: Original file SHA512: " + ToHexString(sha12));

    // Modify file bytes. Here we set byte offset [100] [101] [102]
    WriteBytes(testFile, 100, new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });

    var modifiedSha12 = GetFileSHA512(testFile);
    Console.WriteLine("TestSHA12Modify: Updated file SHA512:  " + ToHexString(modifiedSha12));

    Console.WriteLine("TestSHA12Modify: SHA12 Hashes are: " + (sha12.SequenceEqual(modifiedSha12) ? "EQUAL" : "NOT EQUAL"));
}

static void TestSHA512Append()
{
    var testFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    CreateRandomFile(testFile, 1024);

    var sha12 = GetFileSHA512(testFile);
    Console.WriteLine("TestSHA12Append: Original file SHA512: " + ToHexString(sha12));

    // Append bytes to the end of a file
    AppendBytes(testFile, new byte[] { 1 });

    var modifiedSha12 = GetFileSHA512(testFile);
    Console.WriteLine("TestSHA12Append: Updated file SHA512:  " + ToHexString(modifiedSha12));
    Console.WriteLine("TestSHA12Append: SHA12 Hashes are: " + (sha12.SequenceEqual(modifiedSha12) ? "EQUAL" : "NOT EQUAL"));
}


static void CreateRandomFile(string path, int length)
{
    // Make some random bytes.
    var randomData = new byte[1024];

    RNGCryptoServiceProvider p = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    p.GetBytes(randomData);

    File.WriteAllBytes(path, randomData);
}

static void WriteBytes(string path, int fileOffset, byte[] data)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        fileStream.Seek(fileOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}

static void AppendBytes(string path, byte[] data)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
    {
        fileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}

static byte[] GetFileSHA512(string path)
{
    using (SHA512 sha = new SHA512Managed())
    {
        return sha.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
    }
}

static string ToHexString(byte[] data)
{
    return string.Join("", data.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
}
```